# Magento 1.9.2 get customer address using soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, api, customer-address, shipping-address

following is my code

> $client = new SoapClient('My api url');
>
> $session = $client->login('username', '*********');
>
> $result = $client->customerAddressInfo($session, $address_id);

Following is the error

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [102] Address not exists.

Can anyone explain where am i going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE, can you please share your detail code in question. Your current code is not sufficient for understanding.

Comment: <?php 
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$client = new SoapClient('api url');


$session = $client->login('username', 'password');

$result = $client->customerAddressInfo($session, '4');
var_dump($result);

?>

Comment: I want shipping address of order

Comment: I had alternate solution to get order shipment detail through API. Please check detail in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get order shipment detail via API use below code:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento1921/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('admin', '0f9a9394cb511775b84bbeb88750126d');
$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order.info', '100000205');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result['shipping_address']);
```

Above code will return you order details array including billing, shipping, items, etc.

To get order shipping address user `$result['shipping_address']`.

Hope this will help you.

Note: Please change `API URL`, `Login Detail`, and `Order #` with your detail.

Comment: Thank you Jayesh Patel I had it in my response array itself.

Comment: Great, what you did for that?